# How could I pass data to childView

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

## About

I'm developping ios app with [MXParallaxHeader](https://github.com/maxep/MXParallaxHeader).
I use it in order to create twitter-like UI.
However, I don't know how to pass data from MXScrollView to childViewController when I go MXScrollView page.

## Question

How could I pass data from MXScrollView to childViewController?

## Sample Code

PreviousViewController

```
//MXScrollViewController=ParentVC of MarkerInfoTabViewController
class PreviousViewController:UIViewController {
.
.
    @IBAction func goMXScrollView(_ sender: Any) {
        let nextView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MXScrollViewController") as! MXScrollViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextView, animated: true)
    }
}
```

childViewController

```
//MarkerInfoTabViewController(=childVC of MXScrollView)

import Tabman
import UIKit
import MXParallaxHeader

class MarkerInfoTabViewController: TabmanViewController {

    var marker:Marker!
    private var viewControllers = [UIViewController?]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let leftView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MarkerInfoLeftViewController") as! MarkerInfoLeftViewController
        let rightView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MarkerInfoRightViewController") as! MarkerInfoRightViewController
        
        //↓I　want to pass data here
        leftView.marker = marker

        viewControllers = [leftView, rightView]
        
        self.dataSource = self

        // Create bar
        let bar = TMBar.ButtonBar()
        bar.layout.transitionStyle = .snap // Customize

        // Add to view
        addBar(bar, dataSource: self, at: .top)
    }
}
```

## My App Image

・[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcqHe.jpg)

・[segue to header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1izrU.png)

・[segue to childVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zImWy.png)

## Reference

My app is mostly the same as [this app](https://github.com/yutu/TwitterProfileExample).

Answer (score 2):

Just define a property in the child controller class

```
class ChildViewController {
    var passedData: MY_DATA_TYPE
    ...
```

and set it after the instantiation

```
let nextView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildViewController") as! ChildViewController
nextView.passedData = MY_PASSED_DATA
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextView, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but parentVC is not PreviousVC.
When a user push a button, user goes from PreviousVC to MXScrollVC, and MXScrollVC has childVC.

Comment: @Carabinieri Do it in the same way, just pass your data further.

Comment: MXScrollVC exists only in storyboard. I tried to programmatically create subclass of MXScrollVC but MXScrollVC is written in Objective-c, so I don't understand when it assigns  to MarkerInfoTabVC to childVC property...